# Como puedo imprimir el estudiante con la nota mayor y el estudiante con la nota menor de este JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

Necesito ayuda en este ejercicio y es que necesito imprimir el nombre del estudiante que tiene la nota mas alta, y el estudiante que tiene la nota mas baja del siguiente JSON:

```
/*
   est == estudiantes,
   5.0 == Nota Maxima,
   0.0 == Nota Minima 
*/

var est = [     
    {
        "Codigo": "001",
        "Nombre": "Juan",
        "Nota": 4.0
    }, {
        "Codigo": "002",
        "Nombre": "Felipe",
        "Nota": 4.5
    }, {
        "Codigo": "003",
        "Nombre": "Wilber",
        "Nota": 4.8
    }, {
        "Codigo": "004",
        "Nombre": "Andres",
        "Nota": 2.6
    }, {
        "Codigo": "005",
        "Nombre": "Kelly",
        "Nota": 5.0
    }, {
        "Codigo": "006",
        "Nombre": "Johana",
        "Nota": 3.4
    }, {
        "Codigo": "007",
        "Nombre": "Jaime",
        "Nota": 3.7
    }, {
        "Codigo": "008",
        "Nombre": "Maria",
        "Nota": 1.5
    }, {
        "Codigo": "009",
        "Nombre": "Esteban",
        "Nota": 2.8
    }, {
        "Codigo": "0010",
        "Nombre": "Clara",
        "Nota": 0.9
    }
];
```

Hasta ahora no se como hacerlo..
Ayuda por favor!!

Answer (score 6):

podés ordenar el array según la nota y luego mostrar el primer y último elemento del array ordenado:

```
est.sort(function(a, b){return a.Nota- b.Nota});
est.sort();
console.log(est[0].Nota);
console.log(est[est.length-1].Nota);
```

Espero te sirva. 
Saludos.

Comment: Hola amigo, gracias por responder. Pero me pregunto y como haría para imprimir el "Nombre" del estudiante que tiene esa nota mayor, y después el otro estudiante que tiene la nota menor?.
Que como se ve desde el array, el estudiante con la nota mayor es "Kelly", y el estudiante con la nota menor es "Clara", pero no se como asociar esa nota al estudiante para poder imprimir su nombre

Comment: Hola @JuanFelipe, con la solución de Emilio, ordenas el array según la nota, pero toda la información sigue relacionada, es decir, tendrás los nombres en est[0].Nombre y en est[est.length-1].Nombre